# exit status 1 no matching function for call to 'LiquidCrystal::LiquidCrystal(int, int, int, int, int)'

Tags: arduino-mega

The code below

```
// include the library code:
#include "LiquidCrystal.h"
// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(2,4,5,6,7);

void setup()
{
// set up the LCD’s number of columns and rows:
lcd.begin(16,2);
// Print a message to the LCD.
lcd.print("hello");
}
void loop()
{
// set the cursor to column 0, line 1
// (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
// print the number of seconds since reset:
lcd.print(millis()/1000);
}
```

Gives me the following error:

```
exit status 1 no matching function for call to 'LiquidCrystal::LiquidCrystal(int, int, int, int, int)'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you are missing a parameter in the `lcd()` call. It seem to take six arguments, not five.

From the `Blink` example in the `LiquidCrystal` library:

```
// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
```

Also, looking at the library definition, from `LiquidCrystal.cpp`:

```
class LiquidCrystal : public Print {
public:
  LiquidCrystal(uint8_t rs, uint8_t enable,
        uint8_t d0, uint8_t d1, uint8_t d2, uint8_t d3,
        uint8_t d4, uint8_t d5, uint8_t d6, uint8_t d7);
  LiquidCrystal(uint8_t rs, uint8_t rw, uint8_t enable,
        uint8_t d0, uint8_t d1, uint8_t d2, uint8_t d3,
        uint8_t d4, uint8_t d5, uint8_t d6, uint8_t d7);
  LiquidCrystal(uint8_t rs, uint8_t rw, uint8_t enable,
        uint8_t d0, uint8_t d1, uint8_t d2, uint8_t d3);
  LiquidCrystal(uint8_t rs, uint8_t enable,
        uint8_t d0, uint8_t d1, uint8_t d2, uint8_t d3);
...
}
```

The number of arguments accepted by the various overloaded constructors are (respectively):

- 10
- 11
- 7
- 6

So, your statement:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(2,4,5,6,7);
```

is missing a parameter (or more) as it only has five.

This explains why the error that you are seeing has five `int`s listed in the parameter list:

```
'LiquidCrystal::LiquidCrystal(int, int, int, int, int)'
```